# Creating child processes in Linux

Tags: linux, process, pid

Processes who can create other processes (child processes) and meanwhile the following is correct:

a) The process has PID=0

b) Child process can continue to live independent

c) Process creator copies its context to the child processes

d) All of above are true

My opinion is that a) can't be because PID=0 is reserved, processor creator doesn't copy its context to child processes either, so I am thinking about b, because it can live independent but wouldn't it be called daemon then?? So is there are a correct (True) answer for this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fork() system call creates a clone/copy of the existing process.  Now two processes are running, with the same data, location in the program, and process image.  The difference is the return value of the fork() system call.

Since the fork() function returns different values to the parent (forking) process and the child (forked) process, you can determine whether you are running in the parent or child.

The parent (forking) process receives the result fork() == childpid when in the parent process, so the parent knows the process id of the child (and can thus kill it, wait for it to terminate, etc).

The parent could also receive the result fork() == -1, which indicates that the fork() system call failed.

The child (forked) process receives the result fork() == 0 when in the child process, and should you want to know the process id of the child, you would simply ask the current process id to get the process id of the child.

Here is a related post with code sample I posted, [How to use fork()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147386/system-call-fork-and-execv-function/19151751#19151751).

The subtlety is that (a) is not true, because each of parent and child have a process id which is not =0, but the return from fork() is always =0 in the child.  So it might appear that the manual is saying that the PID is =0.  The part (b) is true.  The part (c) is not true because it is not the process creator that copies anything, it is the system call (in the context of the parent process) which does the copying.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) to know how child process is created. That might well answer your question