# How to use execv for grep?

Tags: c, unix, process, system-calls, execv

My grep is in /bin/usr/grep. 
My child process does run but it does not execute `execv` command.
I am searching for the word "include" in my "ques29.c" file which is shown below :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        perror("Failed to fork.");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        char *argv[] = { "-n", "include", "ques29.c", "NULL" };
        execv("/usr/bin/grep", argv); 
    }
    else
    {
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
        {
            int exit_status = WEXITSTATUS(status);
            printf("Parent: Process ID %ld Exit status of the child was %d\n", (long)getpid, exit_status);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Parent: Process ID 140735031147632 Exit status of the child was 0
```

Comment: @Jabberwocky I tried with NULL but it still doesn't work. Gives me the same output as above.

Comment: Please elaborate _"did not work"_. [Edit] the question and put all clarifications _there_

Comment: This may help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147386/system-call-fork-and-execv-function

Comment: Beware: `"NULL"` is not `NULL`.

Comment: Doesn't an exit status of 0 mean that `grep` found a match? And why are you printing `getpid` which is a function?

Comment: The first element of `argv` should be the path to the program. -> `char *argv[] = { "/usr/bin/grep", "-n", "include", "ques29.c", NULL };`. Your code should check the return code of `execv` and probably return with a non-0 value. In any case you should make sure your child process does not reach the `return 0` in case `execv` fails.

Comment: @Jabberwocky works!! Thank you so much, I need to be more careful.

Comment: Anyway `"NULL"` is wrong that's for sure.

Comment: "but for some reason execv is not returning". What does that mean? If `execv` succeeds it will not return.

Comment: @kaylum With the program in the question exit code 0 will also occur if `execv` fails because then the child will reach the `return 0` at the end of `main()`

Answer (score 4):

Per [the `execv()` Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html):

> v - execv(), execvp(), execvpe()
>
> The char *const argv[] argument is an array of pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the
>          new program.  The first argument, by convention, should point to the
>          filename associated with the file being executed.  The array of
>          pointers must be terminated by a null pointer.

You need to change

```
    char *argv[] = { "-n", "include", "ques29.c", "NULL" };
    execv("/usr/bin/grep", argv);
```

to

```
    char *argv[] = { "/usr/bin/grep", "-n", "include", "ques29.c", NULL };
    execv(argv[0], argv);
```

And as noted in the comments, handling a failed call to `exec*()` should probably be done:

```
    execv(argv[0], argv); 

    // no need to check the return value as
    // a successful call won't return
    perror( "execv()" );

    // note that return and exit() can cause
    // problems with more complex code
    _exit( 255 );
```

Comment: And in case `execv` fails, it may make sense to add something like `return 1;` in order to avoid reaching the final `return 0`.

Comment: @Bodo Adding a `return` would probably be bad in general, although it works in this case.  `_exit()` or similar is usually better.

Answer (score 1):

The array needs to be terminated by a `NULL` pointer, but in your code the last element is a string literal `"NULL"` and the first argument must be the path to the executable:

Instead of this:

```
char *argv[] = { "-n", "include", "ques29.c", "NULL" };
```

You want this:

```
char *argv[] = {"/usr/bin/grep", "-n", "include", "ques29.c", NULL };
```

Comment: I might be thinking of the `exec*l*` versions for the casting thing.